# Is it possible to use EF4.2 Code First and Inverse Property Attribute on the same named property?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4, many-to-many, entity-framework-migrations

I want to know if there is a way to achieve a related list of the same entity on the same class or use migrations to setup a model with this attribute in it?

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("FamilyMembers")]
    public List<Person> FamilyMembers { get; set; }
}
```

At the moment when I am using migrations (AddMigration) to setup the database I get the following exception:

> Add-Migration : A relationship cannot be established from property
>   'FamilyMembers' on type 'ConsoleApplication3.Person' to property
>   'FamilyMembers' on type 'ConsoleApplication3.Person'. Check the values
>   in the InversePropertyAttribute to ensure relationship definitions
>   are unique and reference from one navigation property to its
>   corresponding inverse navigation property.

Also I get the same error adding Person's to the People dbset when running the a test app.

```
        var p1 = new Person();
        p1.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        p1.Name = "p1";

        var p2 = new Person();
        p2.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        p2.Name = "p2";

        var c = new TestContext();
        c.People.Add(p1);
```

Is there another attribute that is not unique and references the same navigation property?

Comment: For this specific example it may make more sense creating a Family entity that has a Members property. Unless you were trying to allow person A to be related to B & C but person B not to C.

Comment: Yep it could do, it is not a proper just one to illustrate a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is no. Each end of the relation must have its own navigation property.